# Why the Angular change my request method to OPTIONS?

Tags: angular

I am implementing JWT Interceptor in Angular.

I follow the example in [here](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/06/22/angular-8-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial) to implement my JWT interceptor, 
my source code as below:

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

@Injectable()
export class JWTInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private cookieService: CookieService) {}
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>,
            next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
              console.log('Interceptor Called');
              if (this.cookieService.check('accessToken')) {
                request = request.clone({
                  withCredentials: true,
                  setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${this.cookieService.get('accessToken')}`
                  }
                });
              }
              return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

My tomcat server respond the following:

HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed
JSPs only permit GET POST or HEAD

When I check the Fire fox console, I found the request method is changed to "OPTIONS", and the Access-Control-Request-Method set to "POST".

[image]

However, when I remove the following code form the header, my tomcat does not response error.

```
setHeaders: {
                Authorization: `Bearer 
                ${this.cookieService.get('accessToken')}`
              }
```

My JSP source as the following:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%
String origin = request.getHeader("Origin");
String VALID_METHODS = "DELETE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST, PUT";
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",origin);
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", VALID_METHODS);
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, Authorization");
System.out.println("Hello");
for (Enumeration<String> e=request.getHeaderNames();e.hasMoreElements();)
{
    System.out.println(e.nextElement());    
}


try
{
    for (Cookie cookie : request.getCookies()) {
        System.out.println(cookie.getName()+"="+cookie.getValue()+";"+cookie.getMaxAge()+";"+cookie.getDomain()+";"+cookie.getPath()+"<br>");
    }
}
catch (NullPointerException e) 
{
    System.out.println("No cookie Detected.");
}

%>
```

I don't know why. And how can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

From the [**Functional Overview of CORS**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Functional_overview):

> the specification mandates that browsers **"preflight"** the request, soliciting supported methods from the server with the HTTP **`OPTIONS`** request method, and then, upon **"approval"** from the server, sending the actual request.

What it means is, this is a specification that expects the browser to check whether CORS is allowed by the server.

The browser checks for it by reading the Response Headers. If they have a **`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`** header present on it with the value **`*`** or the origin with which the request was made, then the browser can be sure that CORS is allowed.

So only If it is, then the actual request would be sent.

This is not something specific to Angular. It's how the browsers implement the CORS Policy.